# Can't use pip, Urllib3 NTLM

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, python-2.x

1 - Environment

pip version: `20.1.1-2`

Python version: `2.x`, `3.0`, `3.8`.

OS: `linux`

2 - How to Reproduce

Just try to use pip.

NOTE: `pythonx -m pip` does not exist

PIP WORK USING `python3.9 -m pip`

3 - Command

```
pip
```

4 - Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/usr/bin/pip”, line 11, in
load_entry_point(‘pip==20.1.1’, ‘console_scripts’, ‘pip’)()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 473, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 2843, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 2447, in load
return self.resolve()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 2453, in resolve
module = import (self.module_name, fromlist=[’ name '], level=0)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py”, line 10, in
from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py”, line 9, in
from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py”, line 7, in
from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py”, line 24, in
from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py”, line 7, in
from pip._vendor import six
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/ init .py”, line 93, in
vendored(“requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.ntlmpool”)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/ init .py”, line 36, in vendored
import (modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
File “”, line 991, in _find_and_load
File “”, line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File “”, line 655, in _load_unlocked
File “”, line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
File “”, line 259, in load_module
File “/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/ntlmpool.py”, line     9, in
File “/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ntlm/ntlm.py”, line 112
print “NTLM_NegotiateUnicode set”
^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to ‘print’. Did you mean print(“NTLM_NegotiateUnicode set”)?
```

I really need help :
I’ve been trying `--reinstall` and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Deep_Thoughts to try help me, dude i solve the error and conflites manually installing pip in each python version using get-pip.py script.

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

I download it and run for every python version. now

```
pip
```

is run right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using the wrong `pip` with the wrong `python` version.

From what I am seeing, you are trying to use the `pip` for `python2.x` with `python3.x`. The most simple solution is to use the corresponding `pip` versions with the `python` version.

For example:

`pip` -> `python2.7`

`pip3` -> `python3 - python3.7` most usually `python3.6`

`pip3.8` -> `python3.8`

and so on ...

### Alternative Solutions include ...

- #### Solution #1:

Go to your `.bashrc` file and add

```sh
alias pip=python3.8 -m pip # 3.8 can be replaced with pip version
```

Save and restart your terminal.

- #### Solution #2:

Uninstall `python3.8` and build it from source. Check this [tutorial](https://dev.to/codejym/how-to-install-python-on-debian-4o8o) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks or the answer, but i just cant use pip, when i try to run the command result in the error. my pip only still work in the python3.9.

When i try execute pip which a module `python -m pip`, except 3.9 version, result in pip does not exist.

Any idea ?

Comment: Wow, It must be the result of a broken python-pip installation, like, the default python installation. Have you tried `sudo apt install python-pip` or `sudo apt install python`. Or those commands with `python3` instead? This is an interesting problem.

Comment: yea i try, purge, reinstall, install. not work :'(

now i change my repo, to dev-src and upgrade, iam waiting end to try again. :(

Comment: Try rebooting your operating system, (if you can) maybe that will fix the issue?